# getting all docutments present in an array in another collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

my Jobs collection is like below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6979339bcdb5d4ae64498f"),
    "jobProfile" : "Java Developer",
    "jobID" : "1",
    "companyName" : "xyz",
    "openingsCount" : 10,
    "jobType" : "Fulltime",
    "jobDescription" : "profile description",
    "contactEmail" : "xyz@gmail.com",
    "contactWebsite" : "www.xyz.com",
    "postingDate" : "07-08-2018 04:21:22",
    "jobstatus" : "Active",
    "jobEndDate" : ISODate("2018-08-14T23:59:59.999Z"),
    "jobEndDateMilliSeconds" : 1534204859999.0
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6aba4c9bcdb5d4ae649197"),
    "jobProfile" : "Python Developer",
    "jobID" : "2",
    "companyName" : "abc",
    "openingsCount" : 10,
    "jobType" : "Fulltime",
    "jobDescription" : "profile description",
    "contactEmail" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "contactWebsite" : "www.abc.com",
    "postingDate" : "07-08-2018 04:21:22",
    "jobstatus" : "Active",
    "jobEndDate" : ISODate("2018-08-14T23:59:59.999Z"),
    "jobEndDateMilliSeconds" : 1534204859000.0
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b6aba4c9bcdb5d4ae64919q"),
    "jobProfile" : "nodejs Developer",
    "jobID" : "3",
    "companyName" : "abc",
    "openingsCount" : 15,
    "jobType" : "Fulltime",
    "jobDescription" : "profile description",
    "contactEmail" : "abc@gmail.com",
    "contactWebsite" : "www.abc.com",
    "postingDate" : "07-08-2018 04:21:22",
    "jobstatus" : "not Active",
    "jobEndDate" : ISODate("2018-08-14T23:59:59.999Z"),
    "jobEndDateMilliSeconds" : 1534204859000.0
}
```

and my User collection is

```
"userID" : "1",
    "userAppliedJobs" : [ 
        "1", 
        "2",
        "3"
    ]
```

i want all the documents having jobID's which are present in userAppliedJobs array of having userID:1 as well as jobStatus is in Active state.

Comment: this should work `{ "$lookup": {
  "from": "jobs",
  "localField": "userAppliedJobs",
  "forignField": "jobID",
  "as": "jobs"
}}`

Comment: Please add your query to the post and try to ask the part which you don't understand.

Comment: @Veeram i am getting array of douctments in a single douctment but i want each douctment individually

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Mongo 3.6 `$lookup` and then a `$projection` with `$filter`:

```
db.getCollection('jobusers').aggregate([
{ $lookup: {
    from: 'jobs',
    localField: 'userAppliedJobs',
    foreignField: 'jobID',
    as: 'userJobs',
  }
},
{ "$project": {
        "id": 1,
        "jobs": {
           "$filter": {
               "input": "$userJobs",
               "as": "job",
               "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$job.jobstatus", "Active" ] }
           }
        }
    }}
])
```

In this example the collection with the 3 jobs is called `jobs` and the one with the single user `jobusers`. Change this to match your names accordingly.

The [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html) part is needed since you a cross-reference with another collection. The somewhat tricky part is the [projection filtering](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/).